# Python, SQL: How to update multiple rows and columns in a single trip around the database?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Hello StackEx community.
I am implementing a relational database using SQLite interfaced with Python. My table consists of 5 attributes with around a million tuples.
To avoid large number of database queries, I wish to execute a single query that updates 2 attributes of multiple tuples. These updated values depend on the tuples' `Primary Key` value and so, are different for each tuple.

I am trying something like the following in `Python 2.7`:

```
stmt= 'UPDATE Users SET Userid (?,?), Neighbours (?,?) WHERE Username IN (?,?)'
cursor.execute(stmt, [(_id1, _Ngbr1, _name1), (_id2, _Ngbr2, _name2)])
```

In other words, I am trying to update the rows that have `Primary Keys` `_name1` and `_name2` by substituting the `Neighbours` and `Userid` columns with corresponding values. The execution of the two statements returns the following error:

```
OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

I am reluctant to use `executemany()` because I want to reduce the number of trips across the database. 
I am struggling with this issue for a couple of hours now but couldn't figure out either the error or an alternate on the web. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the column that is used to look up the row to update is properly indexed, then executing multiple UPDATE statements would be likely to be more efficient than a single statement, because in the latter case the database would probably need to scan all rows.

Anyway, if you really want to do this, you can use [CASE expressions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case) (and [explicitly numbered parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam), to avoid duplicates):

```sql
UPDATE Users
SET Userid = CASE Username
             WHEN ?5 THEN ?1
             WHEN ?6 THEN ?2
             END,
    Neighbours = CASE Username
                 WHEN ?5 THEN ?3
                 WHEN ?6 THEN ?4
                 END,
WHERE Username IN (?5, ?6);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more on the 'properly index'-ing part? How should I go about it?

Comment: By executing [CREATE INDEX](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html). But that is not part of this question.